# Passing an ofstream to a thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've been looking at threads and have run into an error when I try to pass a reference to an ofstream to the thread function:

This is the code:

```
void threader(ofstream& fsOutputFileStream)
{ 
    fsOutputFileStream << "hello";
} 
int main() 
{

  ofstream fsOutputFileStream;
  fsOutputFileStream.open("afile.txt", ios::out);

  thread t(threader, fsOutputFileStream);
  thread u(threader, fsOutputFileStream);
  t.join(); 
  u.join();
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
threadtest.cpp:18: error:   initializing argument 2 of âboost::thread::thread(F, A1) [with F = void (*)(std::ofstream&), A1 = std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >]â
```

If I take the threading bits out and just pass the reference to the function normally there is no problem. 
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but try `std::ref`.

**rationale**: `thread` constructor uses variadic templates to forward the arguments; if [perfect forwarding is not enabled there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327474/does-perfect-forwarding-in-c0x-make-reference-wrapper-deprecated)<sup>1</sup>, you'll need to wrap the reference so it doesn't get passed by value).

```
void threader(ofstream& fsOutputFileStream)
{ 
    fsOutputFileStream << "hello";
} 
int main() 
{

  ofstream fsOutputFileStream;
  fsOutputFileStream.open("afile.txt", ios::out);

  thread t(threader, std::ref(fsOutputFileStream));
  thread u(threader, std::ref(fsOutputFileStream));
  t.join(); 
  u.join();
}
```

P.S. Consider adding synchronization for the output stream...

<sup>1</sup> perfect forwarding requires a [pack expansion like `std::forward<Args>(arguments)...`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template); It might not yet be implemented on your compiler, **or** it might not be used by design (to prevent accidentally sharing data between threads)

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked. Thanks for the rationale as well, I'll need to go and read up some more to fully understand.