# How to pass std::ofstream& into functional params?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code

```
void timer_start(std::function<void(std::ifstream*,std::ofstream&, char*[])> func, unsigned int interval, std::ifstream* ifs, std::ofstream& ofs, char* argv[])
{
    std::thread([func, interval, ifs, ofs, argv]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func(ifs, (std::ofstream&)ofs, argv);
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
        }
    }).join();
}
```

the following error is shown in the second line of the above code while passing **ofs**

**Error C2280   'std::basic_ofstream>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function**

Why this happens and kindly help me out..

Comment: Did you [try the solution offered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093831/passing-an-ofstream-to-a-thread-function).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an ofstream to a thread function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093831/passing-an-ofstream-to-a-thread-function)

Answer (score 1):

You should capture `ofs` by reference, not by value:

```
std::thread([func, interval, ifs, &ofs, argv]()
                                 ^^^^^^
                                  here
```

and probably remove unnecessary cast: `(std::ofstream&)ofs`.

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/vFEJTr)

Comment: C2661 'std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(char *[],std::string,std::ofstream &,void (__cdecl *)(std::thread::id,std::ofstream &)),char **,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>,void (__cdecl *)(std::thread::id,std::ofstream &)>::tuple': no overloaded function takes 5 arguments

Comment: @ArunkumarKathirvel And what am I supposed to do after seeing this error? The code after fixes above compiles successfully with the latest Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: that was my mistake..I got the error out of the above code block...thankyou for trying it..

Answer (score 1):

Change `std::thread([func, interval, ifs, &ofs, argv]()` to `std::thread([func, interval, ifs, &ofs, argv]()`.

As to ofstream you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream)

And perhaps you need to know what the key words [delete and default](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) mean in c++11